# Java IOException on Desktop.getDesktop().open(file)

Tags: java, tomcat

I try to open a pdf file.

I work in a Java project hosted on a Windows Tomcat server.

It works on my local machine, but not on my distant server.

The error message is:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to open file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)
/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/informations.pdf. 
Error message: Access is denied.
```

The Java code:

```
try {
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        ServletContext context = WebContainerServlet
            .getActiveConnection().getServlet().getServletContext();
        File file = new File(context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/resources/informations.pdf"));
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
    }
} catch(Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I open this file?

Comment: what is the os of your distant server? Does the user used to launch tomcat on this server has sufficient rights to access to this file?

Comment: It's a windows server, and yes, tomcat is launched by the Administrator

Comment: Have you tried to do the same thing from a small Java program (outside Tomcat)?

Comment: `Desktop.getDesktop()` runs on the server opens the file for the server with the tomcat's user. That is something completely weird. If you place `informations.pdf` outside `WEB-INF` you can have a link in the browser to it.

Comment: my program is allready small :)

Comment: Joop, where do you think i should place the pdf file exactly?